# Setup Project не отображается ярлык на рабочем столе

Tags: c#, setup

Есть проект установщика. В него добавлен проект(WPF, C#) программы которую нужно установить на ПК. В папку User's Desctop добавлен ярлык exe файла (исполняемый файл запускается нормально) только не отображается иконка. Сам же ехе файл с правильной иконкой а его ярлык нет. Все устанавливается и нормально работает только вместо иконы на рабочем столе ярлык со стандартным значкем. В чем тут может быть дело ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я как-то решал такую же проблему. Я, по-моему, добавлял файл иконки в сам установщик и использовал её. Попробуйте так, расскажите получится или нет?

Comment: @Chloroform А куда именно, в Application Folder ? так она там лежит

Comment: @Сергей Publish -> Options -> Manifests-> галочка у  Create desctop shortcut     делали?

Comment: @LexHobbit нет. сейчас пересоберу

Comment: @LexHobbit никакой разницы увы

Comment: @Сергей только что попробовал с иконкой все ставится ...

Comment: @LexHobbit очень странно. опишите пошагово пожалуйста как вы это сделали.

Comment: @Сергей Project - > Properties -> Application -> Icon and manifwsts указал путь до иконки. Project - > Properties -> Publish -> Options... -> Manifests-> галочка у Create desctop shortcut. Нажал Publish Now   и все. Получил папку с установщиком, где запустил setup. После этого на рабочем столе нашел ярлык с установленным ранее *.ico

Comment: @LexHobbit Как видно из скрина у меня 2 проекта и 1 установщик. Ваш способ не подойдет тк работает только для одного конкретного проекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ход действий такой:

0) Добавляем иконку в корень основного проекта.

1) Добавляем в `Application Folder` иконку.

2) Правый клик по выходным файлам (output files)

3) Жмёт `Creat shortcut to...`

4) Перемещаем ярлык в нужную папку.

5) В свойствах указываем путь до иконки в `Application Folder`

6) Собираем и устанавливаем.

Незабываем указывать нужным папкам свойство: `AlwaysCreate`

Comment: Я именно так все и делаю но ярлык на рабочем столе и в панеле ПУСК все равно выглядит как на картинке.

Comment: @Сергей. Я создал новый проект и произвёл те же действия, у меня всё получилось. Вероятнее всего, мы что-то делаем по разному.

Comment: Я делаю так : В Application Folder добавляю файл ico. В той же папке правой кнопкой по "Основные выходные файлы" -> Create schortcut... Ярлыку ставлю в свойствах Icon ->Browse -> файл иконки в папке Application Folder потом перетаскиваю schortcut в папку Users desctop. пересобираю, устанавливаю - результат тот же. Может дело в размере иконки? 256*256

Comment: @Сергей. В основной выходной проект добавьте ту же иконку

Comment: Лежит в папке с ресурсами

Comment: @Сергей. Добавьте в корень проекта

Comment: И туда тоже добавил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64522/discussion-between-chloroform-and-).